# Trying to setup my MQTT cloud service for my IoT project utilizing Open Source MQTT Broker EMQ

Tags: cloud, cluster-computing, mqtt, iot, emq

I am developing an application to control fan smartly. The smart fan control circuitry comprises Node MCU. There will be two modes of fan control, smart and auto. In the smart mode, the fan's speed could be changed from the predicted value obtained through the application of Machine learning predictive algorithms. The predicted value is generated by python scripts at the server, which the mobile application needs to fetch from the server. I need to have an MQTT broker in between this communication cycle, in which the application will get data from the server through MQTT protocol, similarly, Node MCUs and Mobile Applications will communicate through that MQTT broker. I am using an open-source EMQ MQTT broker. There are two options for the EMQ MQTT broker: one is EMQx and the other is EMQ cloud, whose services are quite expensive. I need to develop my MQTT cloud service in which the MQTT broker software will be open source EMQ broker that would be deployed on my own cloud so that it could be connected to the server and different clients ( Node MCUs and Mobile Applications), thus I would not be needing to avail MQTT cloud services offered by EMQ cloud.

I am a newbie to the internet of things. After research on the internet, I gained this insight to develop this project. Kindly guide me on how to set up this MQTT cloud service so that different clients could be connected to the MQTT broker over the internet.

I will be grateful for your technical assistance.

Comment: I'm sorry but this question is far too broad. There too many choices only you can make about things like security, user management, redundancy. All of these will depend on how you choose to run your service Nd Stack Overflow isn't really the right place to discuss them

Comment: EMQx is free on AWS Marketplace https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B07N2ZFVLX?qid=1591022907049 but you'll have to pay EC2 and transmission charges. We tested 1000 sensors to an EMQx instance https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JUu6nvW6pcE&hd=1

Comment: Why must you use a Cloud-based MQTT broker?  Why not just run something like Mosquitto locally and skip the Cloud costs?  For that matter, if the "Mobile App" and the Node MCU are talking to the same server, why use MQTT at all? A Web socket might be easier.

Comment: I initially run Mosquito locally. To connect it with the Mobile App using Paho client I need to have its IP which could be accessed over the internet. Can I get that IP by hosting it locally ? Also, I think the websocket would only enable it to connect to the browser. Furthermore, I am using MQTT to limit the HTTP requests on the server. Since MQTT is light weight messaging protocol so it would be efficient when we would need to communicate to the devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EMQ X Broker vs EMQ X Enterprise vs EMQ X Enterprise?

#### Diff

1. EMQ X Cloud solves your operation and maintenance and management work. You are not required to operate the security, stability, upgrade, migration and capacity expansion of broker.
2. EMQ X Broker is open source and free, including most functions
3. EMQ X Enterprise provides message storage (such as Kafka, MySQL timescaledb influxdb and dozens of other databases and message queues) and enterprise support services based on broker

#### How to choose?

3. **EMQ X Broker**: if you just use pub sub without data processing, please use EMQ X broker for free
4. **EMQ X Enterprise**: if you want to store message data, use your message (data analysis, storage) and **manage the broker server by yourself**, choose EMQ X Enterprise
5. **EMQ X Cloud**: if you don't want to maintain the server and want to start using it quickly and accept the price, choose EMQ X Cloud

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use emqx public broker: broker.emqx.io:1883 for testing